# Query for fetch two tables data combined

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. 
Table 1 name 'student' have columns like follows

```
rowindex   roll_no  name
1          111      Peter
2          112      John
```

Table 2 name 'exam_dates' have columns like follows

```
rowindex    roll_no    subject      date
1           111        Maths     2018-06-20
2           111        English   2018-06-21
3           112        Maths     2018-06-19
4           112        History   2018-06-22
```

Conditions for query as follows:-

```
Condition 1. Each student's Last exam date in 1 table by using those two tables.
```

&

```
Condition 2. If Exam date is less than today's date, then it should not come into the list.
```

I want to get result as

```
 1. Roll_no 111 have Maths at 2018-06-20 
 2. Roll_no 112 have History at 2018-06-22
```

For get this result what query I have to write?
I tried query as follows:-

```
SELECT a.roll_no, a.name,b.subject, b.date 
FROM test_db.student a, test_db.exam_dates b 
Where a.roll_no = b.roll_no and (SELECT MAX(date) FROM exam_dates) 
group by a.roll_no 
order by a.roll_no, a.name,b.subject;
```

But No success. Need Help.

Comment: "Condition 2. If Exam date is less than today's date, then it should not come into the list." For valid testing you should also provide example data that matches with this  request.. And besides the conditions sounds contradictory because the MAX date doesn't have to be the todays date..

Comment: Sample data, I posted table which I have, what else required?

Comment: If MAX not then which command I should use?

Comment: "If Exam date is less than today's date, then it should not come into the list." the example data doesn't contain dates less then the date today..

Comment: I tried condition1 for testing, if I get result for condition1, then I will try for condition2. But I failed in condition1.

Comment: "If MAX not then which command I should use?" More like `CURDATE()`,  `CURRENT_DATE()` or `DATE(NOW())`

Comment: "the example data doesn't contain dates less then the date today.", We can change table row whenever need to test. But in current scenario, if query satisfy both condition then it should show 2 rows.

Comment: "More like CURDATE(), CURRENT_DATE() or DATE(NOW())", How to use in query, so both condition step by step satisfy? Can you help me to write complete query?

Comment: "Condition 1. Each student's Last exam date in 1 table by using those two tables."  then the results should be `1. Roll_no 111 have English at 2018-06-21 ` and `2. Roll_no 112 have History at 2018-06-22` right?

Comment: You typically group by the columns you select, except those who are arguments yo set functions.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 3):

> Condition 2. If Exam date is less than today's date, then it should not come into the list.

This is a `WHERE` condition.

> Condition 1. Each student's Last exam date in 1 table by using those two tables.

This is `MAX(date)` per student.

You want to show the subject, too, so you'll get the max dates per student first and then query the `exam_dates` table again:

```
select s.roll_no, s.name, ed.subject, ed.date
from student s
join exam_dates ed on ed.roll_no = s.roll_no
where (ed.roll_no, ed.date) in
(
  select roll_no, max(date)
  from exam_dates
  where date >= current_date
  group by roll_no
);
```

Comment: two little errors in the query   roll_no is not aliased it needs to be and `where date < current_date` should be `where date >= current_date`

Comment: After editing it as 's.roll_no' at select, it show 0 row affected. No result.

Comment: Did you check mine complete comment? @MandarKhire it works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02037a/23

Comment: Thanks both, Thorten Kettner & Raymond Nijland. Query Works. I changed exam date before todays date & again checked. It works.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland: Thank you.