# How to use Join in Java program with Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, inner-join, outer-join

I got
[Query for fetch two tables data combined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760008/query-for-fetch-two-tables-data-combined/50760405?noredirect=1#comment88528422_50760405)

I am trying to use it in Java program which work with Hibernate3.
When Ever i try to fetch data, I got exception.
My complete code is in [Question in Coderanch, 1st reply have complete java, xml files.](https://coderanch.com/t/695128/databases/Join-query-hibernate).

Here I my query which I used in java program

```
String selectQuery = "select student.roll_no, student.name, exam_dates.subject, exam_dates.date "
    + "from student student "
    + "JOIN exam_dates exam_dates on exam_dates.roll_no = student.roll_no";
```

and another for trial

```
  String selectQuery = "select student.roll_no, student.name, exam_dates.subject, exam_dates.date "
            + "from student student "
            + "INNER JOIN exam_dates exam_dates on exam_dates.roll_no = student.roll_no";
```

By using it,I get exception as follows:-

```
14:19:07,752  INFO MemoryContextFactory:34 - Creating EJB3Unit initial JNDI context
org.hibernate.QueryException: outer or full join must be followed by path expression [select student.roll_no, student.name, exam_dates.subject, exam_dates.date from student student INNER JOIN exam_dates exam_dates on exam_dates.roll_no = student.roll_no]
at org.hibernate.hql.classic.FromParser.token(FromParser.java:170)
at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClauseParser.token(ClauseParser.java:86)
at org.hibernate.hql.classic.PreprocessingParser.token(PreprocessingParser.java:108)
at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ParserHelper.parse(ParserHelper.java:28)
at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:216)
at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
at test_db.get_table_by_join(test_db.java:99)
at test_db$1.run(test_db.java:40)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can Anyone help me?

Comment: Note that there is no point in giving your `exam_dates` table an `exam_dates` alias.

Comment: I remove alias but no use.

Comment: Just a tip: you may to use @Entity for your classes and define that join on that level using annotations. It helps to refuse a lot of similary errors then.

Comment: Should I change something in student.java or exam_dates.java or xml files for use 'Join' or 'Inner Join' in java program?

Comment: I added @Entity, Column etc in student.java & exam_dates.java, but confuse how 'Join' or 'Inner join' use by that way?

Comment: Use annotations like @OneToMany and JoinColumn on proper fields. A nice tutorial: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: Try using composition in you entity class and use annotations on top of the declaration. Something like below:

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookingRecord", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<BookingDetail> bookingDetails;

Comment: I used '@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)', but still getting 'org.hibernate.QueryException: outer or full join must be followed by path expression'.

Comment: Apologies for the annotation parameters given in comments. Please use only @OneToMany, secondly change you query and remove explicit join in that. Declare ExamDates examdates and after executing the query to select student object just call student.examdates.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer? Can you provide which query I have to use? Should I use '@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)' as annotation in exam_dates.java?

Comment: My final aim to use query which I got as answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760008/query-for-fetch-two-tables-data-combined/50760405?noredirect=1#comment88528422_50760405

Answer (score 1):

Create your entity class as

```
@Entity
public class Student{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long rollNo;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany
    private ExamDates examDates;

    public void setRollNo(Long rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }

    public void getRollNo() {
        return this.rollNo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getExamDates() {
        return this.examDates;
    }

    public void setExamDates(ExamDates examDates) {
        this.examDates = examDates;
    }
}
```

where ExamDates is another class mapping to your exam_dates table. When you will call

```
Student s = entityManager.find(Student.class, rollNo);
```

it will give you student object and then call s.getExamDates which will give you the exam dates

Comment: As per above instruction, is there need to use query for fetching data from two tables? my query is 'select s.roll_no, s.name, ed.subject, ed.date
from student s
join exam_dates ed on ed.roll_no = s.roll_no
where (ed.roll_no, ed.date) in
(
  select roll_no, max(date)
  from exam_dates
  where date <= current_date
  group by roll_no
);'

Comment: above query I used in query browser of mysql & get expected result. Now I am trying to fetch same result in java program.

Comment: @Mandar Khire:  Before I answer that can I know whether you have used hibernate before or not as this requires complex entities and use of Criterion classes, so if you are not aware of all those then I recommend you to please go through all that once.

Comment: I used hibernate for individual tables, not for complex queries.

Comment: In such case use the query itself but remember that HQL is different from SQL and you need to use property name not the column name. Using session.createQuery, you need to provide to this method a HQL query, and not a SQL query. You can use session.createSQLQuery with a SQL query, or write your query as a HQL query, something like:

select cv.field from table1 alias1 JOIN alias1.x alias2, where x is your association element in the first class.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks saurabh Kedia for suggesting me to use 'createSQLQuery', it solve my problem for now. I got answer from you, stackoverflow's other member & coderanch that I have to learn new way to write program for this kind of fetching data. If you know any good book for learn all these techniques then plz suggest me so I can also give answer myself for different queries.

Comment: @MandarKhire If you like my approach please upvote, thanks.